# @interface, @implementaion sections. When to use vs not use?

Tags: objective-c, interface, implementation

So, I am a beginner, learning to program in Objective-C. I understand the concepts of the @interface and @implementation sections and why they're there. But The book I am using will have other examples where it just goes straight to @autoreleasepool, which I find easier to grasp conceptually.

I am definitely missing a key concept of these two sections (@interface and @implementation). Can someone help me understand when you need to use these sections to define the instance variables and their methods, versus entering this info under @autoreleasepool?

What am I failing to comprehend here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@interface` and `@implementation` versus `@autoreleasepool` are used in completely different contexts. As you probably already learned, `@interface` declares a class, while `@implementation` obviously contains the implementation of all the methods. `@autoreleasepool` is used to encapsulate a block of code and make sure that any objects that are autoreleased in this block are released at the end of the `@autoreleasepool` block. Very rarely do you need to create your own `@autoreleasepool` blocks. In most cases there is a single pool that is already created for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using Xcode in terminal mode. For a lot of the exercises I have been putting in the interface, implementation sections, then putting in the autoreleasepool section. Then running the program. Other times Im instructed to just put in an autoreleasepool section and define the variables within. Whats the difference? Im still missing something here...  Thanks for your help.

Comment: With @interface and @implementation you're creating your custom [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_science)). The variables and methods you put in there are part of your class (a class `Vehicle` might have a variable `maxSpeed`, `numberOfPassenger` and methods `start` or `accelerate`).

Comment: If you're using the terminal and are instructed to setup an `@autoreleasepool`, I assume those are relatively simple examples with only one or a few source files. In that case you have to setup a pool, so that an [autoreleased](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) objects in your app are properly released from memory.

Comment: Try creating a template project with Xcode and you'll see that there is an autoreleasepool in the main.h file. That's because every app needs at least one of them. That being said, I wouldn't bother too much about that.

Answer (score -2):

@interface is mainly used for declaring public functions and variables

@implenation is used for private methods and functions (even though in Objective C all member variables and functions are public)